# Aligning multiple line strings c# console app

Tags: c#, console-application, vertical-alignment

I'm making a blackjack game and would like to show the cards next to each other as the player draws them. I have the cards saved as strings within a card object and the strings look sort of like this I couldn't figure out how to actually put it in here:

```
public void CreateDeck()
    {
        myDeck[0] = new Card(1, "hearts", @"
 ______________
| A            |
|              |
|              |
|              |
|    HEARTS    |
|              |
|              |
|            A |
|______________|", @" 
 ______________
|//////////////|
|//////////////|
|//////////////|
|//////////////|
|//////////////|
|//////////////|
|//////////////|
|//////////////|
|//////////////|");
```

The ace of hearts is basically what I would like to output. I can output the cards but every time I output a second card it goes to a new line instead of next to the first card

I would like the output to look like this to display a players and dealers hand

```
 ______________   ______________  
| J            | | 10           |
|              | |              |
|              | |              |
|              | |              |
|     CLUBS    | |    HEARTS    |
|              | |              | 
|              | |              |
|            J | |           10 |
|______________| |______________|
```

Comment: For a console app you can use [Console.SetCursorPosition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition(v=vs.110).aspx), but it seems like a windows app with a grid control would be much easier.

Comment: Please share some code showing Card class and how strings are displayed

Comment: Don't know what you mean by: _output multiple ascii cards next to each other_? You are going to have to show something to go by. What do you want your output to look like and what have you tried that doesn't work?

Comment: Can't tell what you want by the question but maybe `string.Format("{0,10}", cardString);` to make the string 10 characters (or however many you want) wide and right aligned.

Answer (score 0):

You could try redrawing the whole set of cards as they are drawn. Keep the cards in a collection (let's say Cards) with a method to output the art (overriding the public ToString here) Then you will need to split by the carriage return and draw line by line as below. As others have suggested, you will find it much easier (less hacky) to do this in a Windows app.

```
       var cardLines = cards.Select(x =>
        x.ToString().Split('\r').ToList().Select(y => y.Replace("\r", string.Empty).Replace("\n", string.Empty)
        ).ToList()).ToList();
        var maximumCardHeight = cardLines.Max(x => x.Count);
        for (var i = 0; i < maximumCardHeight - 1; i++)
        {
            cardLines.ForEach(x =>
            {
                if (i < x.Count)
                    Console.Write(x[i]);
            });
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Comment: This was really helpful thank you! One problem though, the top of the second card is one space to left from where it should be. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I think it may depend on your card art. You're using the literal string operator followed by a carriage return, which is fed into the splitting. Try getting rid of the carriage return.